# How to create a layer of arrow up shape div with content using HMTL and CSS? Each arrow up shape is hoverable but should only hover inside the arrow

Tags: html, css, hover

I have already tried this but only using an arrow image. But since the div section is shaped rectangular the area without the arrow is still hoverable.

I'd like to ask if there is a way to shape the div as the image below and only make the arrow hoverable.

[image: This is the visual layout of the arrow up]

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and provide the debugging details of your attempt in the form of a [repro] (`<>`-button or `Ctrl + M`). Note, that questions seeking recommendations for tools, libraries, and reference material such as documentation or similar is **off-topic** at SO and not allowed. I changed your question to be within SO's scope and prevent immediate closure of this question.

Comment: how do you shape those arrows? I would assume that you using pseudo-elements at the arrow below. Have you already tried `clip-path`?

Answer (score 0):

Create the arrows not by using pseudo-elements but by using `clip-path`. Clip path will not hide parts of an element but actually cuts them away. That means, that the "invisible parts of the element" actually are not existing and as such `:hover` will not recognize them:

```css
.arrow {
  background-color: red;
  height: 70vh;
  width: 60vh;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 30vh, calc(100% - 10vh) 30vh, calc(100% - 10vh) 100%, 10vh 100%, 10vh 30vh, 0 30vh);
}

.arrow:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}

.offset {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20vh;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow"></div>
<div class="arrow offset"></div>
```